# Return array of struct using function in C

Tags: c, arrays, file-io, struct

I have certain data in a file and want to store it to array of structures in C. I am able to fetch the data but when I set it to the array of struct, each element is replaced with same data.

Can anyone please help me out to read the data and store it to the array of structure.

My code snippet is as follows:

```
int main(){
    FILE * inp;
    char a[20],b[20],c[20],d[20],e[20],f[20];
    struct CD s;
    struct CD cdList[4];
    int i=0;

    inp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    if(!inp)
    {
        printf("Unable ot open file\n");
    }



    while (fscanf(inp,"%s %s %s %s %s %s",&a,&b,&c,&d,&e,&f) != EOF) 
    {
        //printf("%d",i);
        setCD(&cdList[i],a,b,c,d,e,f);
        //cdList[i]=s;
        printCD(&cdList[i]);
        i=i+1;
    }
    //getTopRating(cdList);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 1;
}

/*set function*/
void setCD(struct CD * cd,char artist[] ,char title[],char year[],char genre[],char rating[], char fan[]){
        cd->Artist=artist;
        cd->Title=title;
        cd->Year=year;
        cd->Genre=genre;
        cd->Rating=rating;
        cd->Fan=fan;
}   
/*print structure*/
void printCD(struct CD *cd){
    printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s \n",
        cd->Artist,
        cd->Title,
        cd->Year,
        cd->Genre,
        cd->Rating,
        cd->Fan
        );
}
struct CD{
    char* Artist;
    char* Title;
    char* Year;
    char* Genre;
    char* Rating;
    char* Fan;
};
```

Comment: In `setCD` you probably want to use `new` and `strcpy`.

Comment: How is `struct CD` defined?

Comment: I have added the structure for CD too now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your data is character string, mere copying the pointer is not good. As all `cd->Artist` will point to same location that is `a` (in the `main()`).

Instead of

```
cd->Artist=artist;
```

you should do

```
cd->Artist = strdup(artist);
```

Do this for all string type members you want to store.

Comment: I tried doing that but got Unhandled exception at 0x525bd2e9 (msvcr100d.dll) in Ayush.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xcccccccc. error

Comment: That's because you probably didn't "*...make sure `cd->Artist` has sufficient memory to hold copied string.*"

Comment: how would I allocate the memory for that?

Comment: @Ayush, You haven't shown the definition of `struct CD`. Anyway if `ch->Artist` is `char *` do `cd->Artist=strdup(artist);`

Comment: @Rohan, I get and error message saying my array cdList is corrupted. What might be the reason?